# Find closest match to vector (RGB) with adjustable tolerance in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, rgb

I have an interesting problem. Given a pixel RGB color value (a vector, ie. 255,255,255) and given a database table of all known historical vectors (colors), what is the most efficient/fastest way to find a match in the table?

For example, say I have a light blue (30,144,255) and a table full of thousands of other colors, (but not an exact match to the blue above) - how can I construct a sql query to find me the closest match?

Ideally, if we were looking for an exact match then the query would return nothing but in this example the (30,144,255) blue is not in the table, so we would need some degree of tolerance and/or acceptable distance from the supplied vector.

So we might say, find me a match within n-degrees/percentage/whatever and we could adjust that tolerance to taste.

I've seen logic such as this expressed in C#, C++, etc. but ideally I would like to offset this to the database and I'm not sure how to express this in the most efficient/fastest way.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Colors can be mathematically close in RGB space without being perceived as close by humans. If you map RGB to YUV colorspace first, it will line up better with human vision.

```
DECLARE @R int, @G int, @B int

SELECT TOP(1)
  R,G,B
 ,distance = (Y-@Y)*(Y-@Y)+(U-@U)*(U-@U)+(V-@V)*(V-@V)
FROM MyTable AS rgb
CROSS APPLY (
  SELECT
    Y =              (0.299*R + 0.587*G + 0.114*B)
   ,U = 0.492 * (B - (0.299*R + 0.587*G + 0.114*B) )
   ,V = 0.877 * (B - (0.299*R + 0.587*G + 0.114*B) )
   ,iY =               (0.299*@R + 0.587*@G + 0.114*@B)
   ,iU = 0.492 * (@B - (0.299*@R + 0.587*@G + 0.114*@B) )
   ,iV = 0.877 * (@B - (0.299*@R + 0.587*@G + 0.114*@B) )
) yuv
ORDER BY distance
```

Comment: Thanks - in this case RGB compare should suffice as human eyes aren't involved.

Comment: You'll still want to sort on the Euclidian distance `(x-x1)^2 + (y-y1)^2 + (z-z1)^2` instead of the Manhattan distance `|x-x1| + |y-y1| + |z-z1|`

Answer (score 0):

Not 100% sure why you are doing this, or if I understood correctly, but say you have a table with RGB values, i.e....

```
CREATE TABLE Colors (R int, G int, B int);
```

Then you want to find which row is "nearest" some example colour (say R=128, G=54, B=13), you can find the record with the lowest sum of absolute differences, for example...

```
SELECT R, G, B, ABS(R - 128) + ABS(G - 54) + ABS(B - 13) FROM Colors ORDER BY 4 LIMIT 1
```

Is this what you mean?